# How to calculate GPU utilization of specified process on Windows platform?

Tags: gpu

divided into integrated graphics card and Nvidia graphics card.GPU Performance Monitoring,Generating Log File Upload Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((res = nvmlDeviceGetAccountingStats(device, pids[index], &stat)) == NVML_SUCCESS) {
        qDebug("Gpu mem: %d", stat.memoryUtilization);
        qDebug("GPU: %d%", stat.gpuUtilization);
    } else 
    {
        qDebug("get accounting stat error\n");
    }
```

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer